# Is there any way to rename the path while we select the complex object from mongodb using mongoose in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to rename the path of the fields which are coming from the response.

### My Query:

```
 const allLeads = await Lead.find().select({
    "basic.mobileNumber": 1
  });
res.send({ allLeads });
```

## Response I'm Getting

```
{
  "allLeads": [
    {
      "_id": "5d9f0e2118d1a445bae077aa",
      "basic": {
        "mobileNumber": "1223654789"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d9f16a8cba7744902acb422",
      "basic": {
        "mobileNumber": "1123654789"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## how I want the response

```
{
  _id: 5d9f0e2118d1a445bae077aa,
  mobileNumber: "1223654789"
},

{
  _id: 5d9f16a8cba7744902acb422,
  mobileNumber: "1123654789"
}
```

So is there any way yo archive this using mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this. Is there any other and better way to do this?

```
let simpleLeadInfo = [];
 await SwatiLead.find()
    .select({
      _id: 1,
      "basic.mobileNumber": 1,
    })
    .exec((err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        for (lead in data) {
          const obj = {
            id: data[lead]._id,
            mobileNumber: data[lead].basic.mobileNumber,
          };
          simpleLeadInfo = [...simpleLeadInfo, obj];
        }
        return res.send({ error: false, status: "OK", simpleLeadInfo });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why not push obj to the array instead of using spread? @ravi-singh

Comment: yeah we can do that too i guess!